# RxAndroidBLE perform BLE scan without queueing scan operation

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

In my application I'm using RxAndroidBLE library. Thanks for the awesome library. But I have some issues. I'm trying to connect to BLE device using

`rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)`

Device is out of range. Timeout for connect operation is 30 seconds. At the same time I want to discover other devices using

`rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings)`

But scan operation getting queued and will be performed after connect operation timeout (30 seconds). I can see this behavior in the logs:

```
08-01 17:25:59.978 : QUEUED   ConnectOperation(155884145)
08-01 17:25:59.981 : STARTED  ConnectOperation(155884145)
08-01 17:25:59.989 : Connecting without reflection
08-01 17:26:15.585 : QUEUED   ScanOperationApi21(75017989)
08-01 17:26:18.353 : onConnectionStateChange newState=0 status=133
08-01 17:26:18.361 : Connection operations queue to be terminated (C3:27:5F:B2:60:C9)
08-01 17:26:18.363 : Terminated.
08-01 17:26:18.370 : FINISHED ConnectOperation(155884145) in 18385 ms
08-01 17:26:18.377 : STARTED  ScanOperationApi21(75017989)
08-01 17:26:18.379 : Scan operation is requested to start.
08-01 17:26:18.381 : QUEUED   DisconnectOperation(41108292)
08-01 17:26:18.398 : FINISHED ScanOperationApi21(75017989) in 26 ms
08-01 17:26:18.401 : STARTED  DisconnectOperation(41108292)
08-01 17:26:18.410 : FINISHED DisconnectOperation(41108292) in 10 ms
```

Is this correct and expected behavior? And can I somehow start scan operation immediately without queueing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct and expected behavior?

Yes, this is the expected behaviour. Some BLE stack implementations did not handled well a simultaneous scan and connection which can result in `status=133`. [It is still advised to not to do it](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/wiki/FAQ:-Cannot-connect#connect-while-scanning).

> And can I somehow start scan operation immediately without queueing?

While using the `RxAndroidBle` every scan operation is being queued on the main client queue. While having in mind the above warning you may try to use connection with `autoConnect=true` which will not block the main client queue for long.

Alternatively you can use vanilla Android API to perform the scan.